# How to parse JSON with the Oj SAX parser, Saj

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I want to parse a 10-20MB JSON file, and figure it's probably a good idea to not parse the entire JSON file at once and cause major memory usage. After looking around it seems like [Oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj)'s Saj or ScHandler APIs might be a good fit.

The only problem is that I can't really wrap my head around how to use them, and the documentation doesn't make it much clearer. I've looked at [the example in Saj source code](https://github.com/ohler55/oj/blob/master/lib/oj/saj.rb), and defined a super simple subclass of Oj::Saj like below:

```
class MySaj < Oj::Saj
  def hash_start(key)
    p key
  end
end
```

Used like this:

```
open(URL) do |contents|
  Oj.saj_parse(handler, contents)
end
```

And this leads to a lot of keys from my JSON being printed out. But I still have no idea how to actually access the values belonging to the keys I'm printing.

Can I access the hash itself somehow, or how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Have you tried defining an `add_value` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAX-style parsing is *complicated*.  You have to maintain the state of the parsing, and deal with each state change appropriately.

The `hash_start` and `array_start` callbacks, notify your SAX handler that Saj has found the beginning of a hash, and that the next callbacks that occur will be in the context of that hash.  Note that hashes may be nested, contain (or be contained within) arrays, or simple values.

Here is a simple Saj handler that parses a very simple JSON object:

```
require 'oj'

class MySaj < ::Oj::Saj
  def initialize()
    @hash_cnt = 0
    @array_cnt = 0
  end

  def hash_start(key)
    @hash_cnt += 1
    puts "Start-Hash[@hash_cnt]: '#{key}'"
  end

  def hash_end(key)
    @hash_cnt -= 1
    puts "End-Hash[@hash_cnt]: '#{key}'"
  end

  def array_start(key)
    @array_cnt += 1
    puts "Start-Array[@array_cnt]: '#{key}'"
  end

  def array_end(key)
    @array_cnt -= 1
    puts "End-Array[@array_cnt]: '#{key}'"
  end

  def add_value(value, key);
    puts "Value: [#{key}] = '#{value}'"
  end

  def error(message, line, column)
    puts "ERRRORRR: #{line}:#{column}: #{message}"
  end
end

json = '[{ "key1": "abc", "key2": 123}, { "test1": "qwerty", "pi": 3.14159 }]'

cnt = MySaj.new()
Oj.saj_parse(cnt, json)
```

The results of this basic JSON parsing with Saj gives this result:

```
Start-Array[@array_cnt]: ''
Start-Hash[@hash_cnt]: ''
Value: [key1] = 'abc'
Value: [key2] = '123'
End-Hash[@hash_cnt]: ''
Start-Hash[@hash_cnt]: ''
Value: [test1] = 'qwerty'
Value: [pi] = '3.14159'
End-Hash[@hash_cnt]: ''
End-Array[@array_cnt]: ''
```

You may notice that this output is roughly equivalent to one callback per token (omitting ',' and ':').  You essentially have to build into your callbacks the knowledge of what to do with individual JSON elements.  Along those lines, you also need to build the hierarchy described by the callbacks.  For example, when `hash_start` is called, push an empty hash on the stack; when `hash_end` is called, pop the hash or move back one level in the hierarchy.

For example you could have a handler in `hash_end` that checks to see if this is ending a top-level hash, and when it is, then do something with that hash.  Note that you can often not do this with arrays, as the top-level element in a very large number of JSON documents is an array, so you have to determine when the array is the top+1 level array.

If you like writing compiler backends, this is the JSON parsing solution for you.  Personally, I've never enjoyed working in Sax, but for large documents, it can be very resource-friendly and highly performant, depending on how well you write the handler.  Be prepared for oodles of debugging and slightly mismatched state management, as that's par for the course with Sax-style parsing.

However, you shouldn't be too concerned with 10-20MB JSON, as that's actually not very large.  I've processed 80+MB JSON with "regular" Oj (`load` and `dump`) quite a lot, and not had a problem with it.  Unless you're running on a *severely* resource-constrained machine, the standard Oj will work well for you.

Comment: Thanks for the very clarifying answer, and recommendations! This is something that will be running on a Heroku, so I won't have huge amounts of memory available. It seems like this stuff is painful enough that I should at least make some effort to check if loading it all at once is viable.

Answer (score 2):

Saj is a streaming parser. What that means, in practice, is that it doesn't know a file's contents in their entirety and parses them whole — it instead notifies you of parse events as it encounters them. Your thinking is solid: the larger the file, the more you benefit from parsing in that manner if you wish to pick and choose from it.

`hash_start` is one such event, fired when Oj sees the beginning of an Object (which will become a `Hash` in Ruby land).

Take this JSON for instance:

```
{
  "student-1": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 42,
    "knownAliases": ["Blabby Joe", "Stack Underflow"],
    "trainingGrades": {
        "Advanced Zumba Dancing": "A+",
        "Introduction to Twitter Arguments": "C-"
    }
  },
  "student-2": {
    "name": "Rebecca Melecca",
    "age": 26,
    "knownAliases": ["Booger Becca", "Tanktop Terror"],
    "trainingGrades": {
        "Intermediate Groin Kickery": "A+",
        "Advanced Quantum Mechanics": "A+"
  }
}
```

And the following parser:

```rb
class StudentParser < Oj::Saj
  def hash_start(key)
    puts "hash_start(#{key.inspect})"
  end

  def hash_end(key)
    puts "hash_end(#{key.inspect})"
  end

  def array_start(key)
    puts "array_start(#{key.inspect})"
  end

  def array_end(key)
    puts "array_end(#{key.inspect})"
  end

  def add_value(value, key)
    puts "add_value(#{value.inspect}, #{key.inspect})"
  end
end
```

And you'll get the following sequence of events:

```
hash_start(nil)
hash_start("student-1")
add_value("John Doe", "name")
add_value(42, "age")
array_start("knownAliases")
add_value("Blabby Joe", nil)
add_value("Stack Underflow", nil)
array_end("knownAliases")
hash_start("trainingGrades")
add_value("A+", "Advanced Zumba Dancing")
add_value("C-", "Introduction to Twitter Arguments")
hash_end("trainingGrades")
hash_end("student-1")
hash_start("student-2")
add_value("Rebecca Melecca", "name")
add_value(26, "age")
array_start("knownAliases")
add_value("Booger Becca", nil)
add_value("Tanktop Terror", nil)
array_end("knownAliases")
hash_start("trainingGrades")
add_value("A+", "Intermediate Groin Kickery")
add_value("A+", "Advanced Quantum Mechanics")
hash_end("trainingGrades")
hash_end("student-2")
hash_end(nil)
```

When you see `hash_start(nil)`, it means the parser has found a top-level object (that very first opening brace). Conversely, `hash_end(nil)` means that top-level object has been closed, and its innards properly parsed (i.e. no parsing erros have been found).

Parsing in this manner means you have to keep track of nesting, if that's meaningful to you, of adding keys and values at the right value, et cetera. That makes it annoying and hard, but worthwhile if you wish to carve out bits of a large file without committing everything to memory.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and useful answer! I'm finding both answers useful, but marking Michael Gaskill's answer as the accepted because it also had useful input on my concrete case (10-20MB JSON)

Comment: No problem, his was great.